# How to use PFX file to avoid website security certificate error

Tags: ssl-certificate, pfx

We do have an application(Qlik Nprinting) in Azure VM server running with an application in-built web server(not IIS). Due to port conflicts, we haven't installed IIS in the server. In order to avoid the error "There is a problem with the website security certificate" while launching the application web portal, we requested certificates team for SSL certificate. But they have provided us with .PFX file and told us to install in our server.

The certificate team has generated a CSR file from their end and created .PFX and shared it to us. When googled how to use .pfx file the steps were shown for IIS server, but in our case, we do not use IIS.

Could you please guide me on the steps how to use .pfx file in our server(which do not has IIS) to avoid the website security certificate error.

Comment: This will be helpful:
https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-NPrinting-Discussions/Install-SSL-certificate-to-NPrinting/td-p/1238004

Comment: @ImranKhan Thanks for your reply. I have gone through the link you have mentioned. My question is different from the one in the link. My question here is, in general, how can I use .pfx file in a server (in which IIS is not installed) to avoid certificate error.

Comment: If you are not using IIS, then you will be using some other web server. So answer will depend upon what you are using. Above answer is specific to Qlik which you mentioned in your question.